# Group Values between date time range

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

And I want to group the data order by the daydifference=1, the rows where the daydifference is bigger than 1, will be grouped between the days that have difference=1. So this will be like this:

[image]

So I tried this way:

```
SELECT 
    InicialData
    ,FinalDate
    FROM #ValueAnalysis
    WHERE WorkDays=1
    GROUP BY InicialData, FinalDate
```

And now I want to join the orders where the daydifference is bigger than 1.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Questions: 1) Which version of SQL Server do you use? 2) What is the difference between WorkDays and DayDifference columns? 3) What is the expected result if you have `1/1/2019` `4/1/2019` as values for the last row?

Comment: I have SQL server 2017; 2) daydifference counts the number of days between the initial date and final date ; 3) then the order number shoul appear on day 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQL Server 2017 or newer, you can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). For example like this:

```
SELECT va.InitialDate, 
       va.FinalDate, 
       STRING_AGG(cc.Order_,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cc.Order_ ASC) as Order_1
FROM ValueAnalysis va 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT Order_
    FROM ValueAnalysis 
    WHERE va.InitialDate = InitialDate or va.FinalDate = FinalDate
) as cc
WHERE DayDiff = 1
GROUP BY va.InitialDate, va.FinalDate
```

Output:

```
| InitialDate |  FinalDate | Order_1 |
|-------------|------------|---------|
|  2020-01-02 | 2020-01-02 |   21,23 |
|  2020-01-03 | 2020-01-03 |      22 |
|  2020-01-04 | 2020-01-04 |   23,24 |
```

**EDIT#1**

If you need generate new table and include dates that are not in original dataset, then you can use recursive CTE:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT MIN(InitialDate) InitialDate, 
           MAX(FinalDate) FinalDate, 
    FROM ValueAnalysis
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,InitialDate)
           FinalDate
    FROM cte
    WHERE InitialDate < FinalDate
)

SELECT c.InitialDate InitialDate, 
       c.InitialDate FinalDate, 
       STRING_AGG(va.Order_,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY va.Order_ ASC) as Order_1
FROM cte c 
LEFT JOIN ValueAnalysis va
    ON va.InitialDate = c.InitialDate or va.FinalDate = c.InitialDate
GROUP BY c.InitialDate, c.FinalDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100)
```

Comment: this works, but imagine that I have another row where InitialDate: 2020-01-04 and final date 2020-01-06?

Comment: It is a question to you actualy :) how it should be handled if there are no rows for 2020-01-06 with DayDiff = 1?

Comment: Actually I think the best would be to create a new row with the dates from 4 to 6..